# problem to search a word in pdf file with “Document Viewer”?

Tags: language-support, document

I can't search Persian words. In fact I should search the reserve form of that word to find it . how can I fix this problem by searching the right form of that word ?

example :
if the word is : بلوک
I should search it : کولب
how can i fix this ?

Output of `locale`:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=fa_IR
LC_TIME=fa_IR
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=fa_IR
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=fa_IR
LC_NAME=fa_IR
LC_ADDRESS=fa_IR
LC_TELEPHONE=fa_IR
LC_MEASUREMENT=fa_IR
LC_IDENTIFICATION=fa_IR
LC_ALL=
```

Comment: Was the PDF document created using UTF-8 encoding?

Comment: try this: open terminal type `env LANG="fa_IR"  evince &`. this will open document reader and then open the document you like (Ctrl + O) and then try searching (dont open document by double clicking it)

Comment: @ edward torvalds didn't work , by the way , I can select the text in the pdf file it is not image .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*This wont solve your problem but will act as better alternative*

Document viewer is not a good PDF reader. I recommend installing the best PDF reader available for linux, Foxit Reader.

**It's compatible with Farsi.**

[Download Foxit PDF Reader for linux](https://www.foxitsoftware.com/downloads/)

Comment: I use Farsi texts a lot and this is the only app that works fine with this language beside Adobe Acrobat.